# Why is my state value not updating when I need it in nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jwt

I am trying to update my token variable when the token has expired. I can see that the refresh endpoints goes succeessfully and generates new access token and refresh token. However, the function to update token does not work and I don't know why. Same function works on refresh. I am using axios for the API calls. I would like the axios interceptor to work and intercept an expired token, then call the refresh route to generate new access token and refresh token, attach the access token on the token variable and make an api call again.

I have the following sample codes:

```
  const refreshToken = async()=>{

  const getItem = localStorage.getItem('path');
  const refreshData = {
    refresh: getItem,
   
  }


   
   if(getItem){
    try {
      const res = await axios.post<axiosGetRefreshTokenAttributes>(`${BASE_URL}/refresh`, refreshData);

      const accessToken = res?.data?.userToken
      const userRefresh = res?.data?.refreshToken
     
        localStorage.removeItem('path');
        localStorage.setItem('path', userRefresh as string)
        
        
      dispatch({type: actionEnum.SET_IN_MEMORY_VARIABLE, payload: accessToken})// This reduce function to set the new token on the variable state. Does not work.
      return accessToken
    } catch (error) {
      return error
    }
   }

}

  return refreshToken
 };
```

This is the interceptor code:

```
 const useAxiosPrivate = () =>{

const refreshToken = RefreshFunction()
const {state, dispatch, } = useContext(BookingContext);


useEffect(() =>{
  
    const requestInterceptors = axiosPrivate.interceptors.request.use(
        config =>{
            if(!config.headers['authorization']){
                config.headers['authorization'] = `Bearer ${state?.in_memory}`
            }
            return config;
        }, (error) => Promise.reject(error)
    );

    const responseIntercept = axiosPrivate.interceptors.response.use(
        response => response,
        async (error)=>{
            const prevRequest = error?.config;
            console.log(error.response.status, 'kkk')
            if(error?.response.status === 401 && !prevRequest?.sent){
                prevRequest.sent = true;
               
                const getToken = await refreshToken()
               
                
                
                 prevRequest.headers['authorization'] = `Bearer ${state?.in_memory}`;
                
                 return axiosPrivate(prevRequest);
                
               
            }
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }
    );

    return()=>{
        axiosPrivate.interceptors.request.eject(requestInterceptors)
        axiosPrivate.interceptors.response.eject(responseIntercept)
    }



  }, [state?.in_memory])

  return axiosPrivate;


     };


  export default useAxiosPrivate;
```

The useReducer function to update the token state:

```
    case actionEnum.SET_IN_MEMORY_VARIABLE:
        return{
            ...state,
            in_memory: action.payload
        }
```

This `useEffect` function code runs and works and it properly updates the token states. This is to cover when the user refreshes the page.
` const getRefresh = async ()=>{

```
        if(state?.in_memory === null || state?.in_memory === undefined){
           
            const getToken = await refreshToken();

            dispatch({type: actionEnum.SET_IN_MEMORY_VARIABLE, payload: getToken})
            
        }`
```

The problem is that on intercepting the code when the token has expired, the refresh route successfully generates the code but doesnt update the state. What Am I doing wrongly?